# Design pattern for requiring children of a base class to call a method from the base class

Tags: c#, .net, design-patterns, polymorphism

Let's say I have a base class

```
public class BaseAuthenticator
{
    protected void AuthenticateSuccessfully()
    {
        // Do stuff
    }
}
```

And I have many types of authenticators all deriving from the base class.
I only want one thing from the derived classes : It's that they don't forget to call `AuthenticateSuccessfully()` somewhere in their code. All authenticators have their own logic, but in the end they should always call `AuthenticateSuccessfully()` somewhere when ready to do so (after validations, etc.).

How can I ensure at compile time that every derived authenticator calls the `AuthenticateSuccessfully()` method at least once?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Template method pattern can work in this scenario (This is at runtime)

```
void Main()
{
    var authenticators = new List<UserQuery.BaseClass>();
    authenticators.Add(new ConcreteClassA());
    authenticators.Add(new ConcreteClassB());
    foreach (var authenticator in authenticators)
    {
        authenticator.TemplateMethod();
    }
}


public abstract class BaseClass
{
    public abstract void Validate();

    public void AuthenticateSuccessfully()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Base Class Authentication");
        // Do Stuff Specific to base class
    }

    public void TemplateMethod()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Template method called");
        Validate();
        AuthenticateSuccessfully();
    }
}

public class ConcreteClassA : BaseClass
{
    public override void Validate()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Validate Method of ConcreteClassA");
       //Do Whatever here Specific to the Concrete class A
    }
}

class ConcreteClassB : BaseClass
{
    public override void Validate()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Validate Method of ConcreteClassB");
        //Do Whatever here Specific to the Concrete class B
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Through design patterns alone, this cannot be achieved. By definition a derived class is free to perform as it wishes.

Now you mentioned at the end that you want to validate this is true at compile time. That is a completely different approach. I assume you are wanting to basically perform an "auto code review" by alerting the developer of violations. There are static code analysis tools in which you may be able to write a rule to perform that validation. Possibly JetBrains ReSharper. See this SO post: [How to add custom code analysis in ReSharper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2264335/how-to-add-custom-code-analysis-in-resharper)

Comment: This answer makes more sense because understand that if child class developer does not call `base.AuthenticateSuccessfully` things will fail, so it's more of their headache than yours. You need to make sure that you properly document/comment your class/method that others will not miss calling it. Interesting question.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for the Template Pattern. You can have some abstract method in the base like `bool loginAttempt()` and, in the base class, call the `AuthenticatedSuccessfully()` if the attempt returned true, for example.

This is not exactly what you're looking for (making sure at compile time that derived classes call some methods), but in the terms of *ensuring a behavior for the derived classes*, the Template Pattern is spot on.